# Подходит ли данная архитектура нейронной сети для классификации текстов?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

**Код:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=15,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2)
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                        batch_size=256)
```

Есть ли более подходящие/эффективные варианты архитектуры нейронной сети для классификации текстов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - это несоответствие выбранной функции активации и функции потери (ошибки). Функция активации `sigmoid` используется для бинарной классификации и используется в сочетании с функцией потери: `binary_crossentropy`.

Если результатом классификации может быть более двух (3+) значений, то в качестве функции активации следует использовать `softmax`, а в качестве потери `categorical_crossentropy`.

Наиболее подходящая архитектура - это та, которая дает самые лучшие **для вас** результаты и удовлетворяет всем **вашим** граничным условиям.